# How to extract protocols (http)[s] to check url using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, kali-linux, termux-linux

### I have tried below one:

---

```bash
A=https://xyz.site
echo -e ${A//:*}
```

*Result*: **`https`**

---

**Please describe me that, how this `${A//:*}` term results https or http and what's the concept behind it, share a article or pdf if possible.**

---

### For Worldwide web [www]

**Its preety simple to extract this one:**

---

```bash
A=www.google.com
echo -e ${A::3}
```

---

*Result*: **`www`**

Comment: What do you mean by "how it done"? Which kind of "concept" are you searching for?

Comment: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${parameter:offset:length}` — This is referred to as [Substring Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). In your example `${A::3}` means `${A:0:3}` and returns the first 3 characters of the variable `A`.

`${parameter/pattern/string}` — This notation [replaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) the first match of pattern with a string. If pattern begins with `/`, all matches of pattern are replaced with string. In your example `${A//:*}` means `${A//:*/}` and it replaces all patterns `:*` with an empty string.